# How can a woman give birth under epidural anesthesia?

Tags: birth, anesthesia, instinct, epidural

My girlfriend is curious about the following. Can a woman, when anaesthetised, "push" while giving birth since she can't really feel anything? How is it possible?

Comment: are you sure you mean general? A person under general is unconscious. They don't just not feel, they don't hear, see, etc. You might mean epidural. That's the spinal injection that blocks sensation. It can be "turned down" to allow sensations associated with pushing to get through.

Comment: Exactly thats what I meant, I'll change my question right away.